# Migration of Project Webcenter Portal Framework Application from JDeveloper11g to JDeveloper 12c

Tags: jdeveloper

I decided to upgrade my existing JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 to new version 12.2.1.3.0

As stated above in title, I found that my project got problem to run in the new JDeveloper. I found that some of the library used in oldest version cannot be reference. 
E.g. WebCenter Virtual Content Repository, Webcenter Page Service, WebCenter Collaboration Common, etc

Also, base on my finding from [oracle](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2078796_1.html), stated that "**The WebCenter Portal Framework is not available in the WebCenter Portal 12c release.**"

Can anyone please advice how should I work with my project by using the new JDeveloper. Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already get an answer from Oracle official support. Conclusion is, it is NOT feasible to continue to develop existing Webcenter Portal Framework Application using newest JDveloper 12c

below is their reply

> I understand your purpose is to use Jdev 11g to continue develop your portal framework application and do incremental deployment to WCP 12c. However, this is not feasible. 
>   The migrating path provided is for migrated old portal framwork application to 12c in only 1 time. not incremental upgrade.  If you need to update to portal framework application and you do it from Jdev 11g, you have to repreat the steps, that means you have to upgrade 11g portal to 12c portal again.
>
> In summary, there are no way to use Jdev 11g to CONTINUE develop a portal app and deploy to WCP 12c, If you want to continue add new assets/content to your migrated app,I think you can use Jdev 12c to create WebCenter Portal Asset application. 
>   reference: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wcp/develop/GUID-D013EB98-A5BB-47A1-8931-A808F7806049.htm#JPSDG15334